# .NET Framework 4.5.2 versioning

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework, version

Can .NET Framework 4.5.2 be deployed on a clean Windows 7 system (which does not include .NET Framework 4)? In other words, can .NET Framework 4.5.2 be installed without previously installing 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found the answer.

From the user standpoint, due to backward compatibility, the 4.5.2 redistributables deployment should completely supersede the need for previous ones, whichever is the version targeted by the application.

[According to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Targeting and Running .NET Framework 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, and 4.5.2 apps:
>
> The .NET Framework 4.5 is an in-place update that replaces the .NET Framework 4 on your computer, and similiarly, the .NET Framework 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 are in-place updates to the .NET Framework 4.5. After you install one of these updates, your .NET Framework 4 or .NET Framework 4.5 apps should continue to run without requiring recompilation. However, the reverse is not true. We do not recommend running apps that target the .NET Framework 4.5.1 or 4.5.2 on the .NET Framework 4.5. The following guidelines apply:
>
> - In Visual Studio 2013, you can choose the .NET Framework 4.5 as the target framework for a project (this sets the GetReferenceAssemblyPaths.TargetFrameworkMoniker property) to compile the project as a .NET Framework 4.5 assembly or executable. This assembly or executable can then be used on any computer that has the .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1, or 4.5.2 installed.
> - In Visual Studio 2013, you can choose the .NET Framework 4.5.1 as the target framework for a project (this sets the GetReferenceAssemblyPaths.TargetFrameworkMoniker property) to compile the project as a .NET Framework 4.5.1 assembly or executable. This assembly or executable should be run only on computers that have the .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed. An executable that targets the .NET Framework 4.5.1 will be blocked from running on a computer that only has the .NET Framework 4.5 installed, and the user will be prompted to install the .NET Framework 4.5.1. In addition, .NET Framework 4.5.1 assemblies should not be called from a .NET Framework 4.5 app.

Also, [regarding the redistributables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Installation notes:
>
> - The .NET Framework 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 are in-place updates to the .NET Framework 4.5.
> - The .NET Framework 4.5 and its point releases replace the .NET Framework 4. When you install these versions on a system that has the .NET Framework 4 installed, the assemblies are replaced.
> - Uninstalling the .NET Framework 4.5 also removes pre-existing .NET Framework 4 files. If you want to go back to the .NET Framework 4, you must reinstall it and any updates to it.

Comment: @Ramhound -  I'm sorry, I am afraid I don't understand what you mean. Regarding the system requirements, they are not related to my original question at all. The question was if the deployment of version 4.5.2 would be enough or if it had to be deployed after 4 in order to update it (since Microsoft calls it in-place update).

Comment: Yes, I've read it and nowhere does Microsoft answer that question. It says: "This version of the .NET Framework runs side-by-side with the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and earlier versions, but performs an in-place update for the .NET Framework 4, .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET Framework 4.5.1." That was precisely the ambiguity that lead me to ask this question. In any case, if you see the answer somewhere in that page, please feel free to edit the answer. Thanks for the heads-up, I've added the sources.

Comment: I make suggestions for a very specific reason.  Personally I don't see the ambiguity, it specifically says its an in-place upgrade, but I suppose I have come to learn Microsoft speak.  When they indicate something is an in-place upgrade it means upgrading to it will replace it.  The verb-age is important.